# Get fields from array

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working on a facebook app to retrieve information from the user. The overall goal is to make a "interactive story" about the user. So I want the name, birthday etc. But I also want to know their favorite bands. The problem is that I can display the array with all the info needed. But that is to much. I don't want to know the category or the id, I only want to know the name.

```
$user_music = $facebook->api('/me/music');
print_r ($user_music);
```

If I use this code, I get something like this:

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [category] => Musician/band [name] => Red Hot Chili Peppers [created_time] => 2011-03-21T15:01:57+0000 [id] => 8335563918 ) 
[1] => Array ( [category] => Musician/band [name] => Train [created_time] => 2011-03-21T15:01:57+0000 [id] => 15313895735 ) )
```

I only want the bands name, but if I use this code:

```
$user_music = $facebook->api('/me/music');
$music_name = $user_music["name"];
echo $music_name;
```

it says it doesn't know "name".

Comment: you need to loop the data array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed 1 array level. To access "name" you should use:

```
$user_music["data"][0]["name"]
```

or to get all names you should iterate

```
foreach($user_music["data"] as $data) {
    echo $data["name"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what i needed! i'll accept your answer in 6 minutes ;)

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this:

```
$user_music['data'][0]["name"]
```

or run $user_music['data'] in a foreach loop